# Windows Server 2008 R2 DFSR Backlog Troubleshooting - Where to look for the cause of the problem?

Tags: windows-server-2008, dfs-r

Windows Server 2008 R2 DFS Backlog Troubleshooting

dfsrdiag indicates our target server has hundreds of thousands of backlogged transactions.

Our authoritative source server indicates it has no backlogged transactions. No replication is taking place. Tests with plain text files aren't replicating.

dfsrdiag propogation tests fail to propogate.

I've restarted the DFS services. I've restarted the servers. I've created new DFS shares to test with. The authoritative source server indicates it has no backlogs and the target indicates it has backlogs (which are the files it's waiting to receive). Files don't replicate in either direction.

2x Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard servers
One server is at each of two sites
The DFS shares are on each respective server
\site_1_server_1\users
\site_2_server_1\users
The sites are connected by a T1

DFSR worked for a week. I added a new share, another folder on the same servers, and that replicated for a weekend but never finished. Then all replication stopped.

Is Windows DFS flaky?
What tools should I use and what should I look at to identify what's causing this problem?

Comment: any event log entries?

Comment: A few watermark entries but less than one watermark entry per day. I have the staging set to 32 GB. The share is only 150 GB.  This is confusing because dfsrdiag says the backlog is increasing, the folder/file counts aren't changing, and health report says the new share is still awaiting initial replication, etc. so some things appear to indicate replication has stopped, but the watermark entries indicate files are moving around at least in the staging folder.

Comment: I realize this is months old, but are you still having a problem? I came across the question from the "related" list. 
You could check the DFSR debug log on your servers, located at c:\windows\debug\dfsrxxx.log. Do a find for "error" or "warning", and use this blog series to help pin-point an issue: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/03/23/understanding-dfsr-debug-logging-part-1-logging-levels-log-format-guid-s.aspx